# Debouncing function firing immediately

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I am trying to make the code inside `updateValidation` function work after 800ms but it's firing immediately. This code was working well in procedural coding but looks like it does not like OOP:

```
eventListeners(){
        document.querySelector('.main_width').addEventListener('input', e => {
            let alertMsgBox = document.querySelector('.height_alert_msg');
            let alertMsg = document.querySelector('.height_alert_msg span');
            
            // let check = ;
            this.debounce(
                this.updateValidation( e.target.value, 12, 41, alertMsgBox, alertMsg, 'str_height' ), 800
             )
        });
    }

    updateValidation( value, min, max, alertEl, alertMsg, param ){
        let message;

        console.log('works');
        if( value > max ){
            alertEl.classList.add('active');
            
            if( param == 'str_height' ){
                message = "Can't be over 41 ft";
            }
            
            alertMsg.innerText = message;
        } else if( value < min ){
            alertEl.classList.add('active');
            
            if( param == 'str_height' ){
                message = "Can't be below 12 ft";
            }
            
            alertMsg.innerText = message;
        } else {
            alertEl.classList.remove('active');
            alertMsg.innerText = '';            
        }
    }
    
    debounce(func, delay){
        let timeout;
        
        return (...args) => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout( () => {
                func(...args)
            }, delay)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask [your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832672/cant-pass-a-parent-function-argument-to-its-sub-function). The used debouncer type returns a callback function to attach to an event, it's used like  `.addEventListener('input', debounce(callback, delay));`. Notice also, that the argument values are passed when a function is invoked, not when it's defined.

Comment: @Teemu I am very sorry. I had deleted and also flagged that post with the explanation for admins.

Comment: OK, to me that old question looked fine. As long as there are no answers to your question, you can edit and modify the question as you wish. If an answer is posted, then you should not change the intention of the question, as that makes a posted answer deprecated.

Comment: @Teemu thank you very much. I will keep this in mind for future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `debounce` method is supposed to take a function, and returns a (wrapped) function that can be called in place of it. You're calling `debounce` with the *result* of calling your method immediately. Check the difference between the two below examples using your debounce code

```js
function debounce(func, delay) {
  let timeout;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args)
    }, delay)
  }
}

function test(msg) {
  console.log(msg, new Date());
}

console.log("time start", new Date());

debounce(test("Wrong usage - will run immediately!"), 1000);

var debouncedTest = debounce(test, 1000);
debouncedTest("Correct usage - will run after 1s");
```

You can fix your code as follows:

```
document.querySelector('.main_width').addEventListener('input', debounce(e => {
    let alertMsgBox = document.querySelector('.height_alert_msg');
    let alertMsg = document.querySelector('.height_alert_msg span');
    this.updateValidation( e.target.value, 12, 41, alertMsgBox, alertMsg, 'str_height' );
}, 800);
```

---

Edit: You still seem a little confused how this function works. Hopefully this snippet might make it a bit clearer. The purpose of a debounce function is to stop the wrapped method firing too often. The below example writes the content of the textbox to the console, but only after you stop typing for 1 second:

```js
function debounce(func, delay) {
  let timeout;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func(...args)
    }, delay)
  }
}

document.getElementById("debouncedBox").addEventListener("input", debounce(e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
},1000));
```

```html
<input id="debouncedBox">
```

Comment: Looking at your edited reply and the new snippet you added, aren't you calling the `debounce` function here too immediately with that `debounce( e => { ....})` ? It is no more just a function name but the whole function wrapped with the `e` value? Isn't that the same mistake I was doing in the original code? Could you please explain in a gist? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Coder No, it's absolutely NOT the same. You were executing a function and passing the _result_ of that function to the `debounce` method. I am passing a _reference to a function_ which is wrapped in the debounce and set as an event handler. See my edited example, hopefully that makes it clearer.